# Event communication between threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, events

I am trying the set an [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) to communicate between 2 threads, but the event is never set in the second thread, here is what I tried so far :

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time

class Test1(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, event):
        super(Test1, self).__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        self.event.set()
        print('event set')

class Test2(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, event):
        super(Test2, self).__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.isSet():
            self.event.wait()
            print('event wait ended')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = threading.Event()

    test1 = Test1(event)
    test2 = Test2(event)

    test1.start()
    test2.start()

    test1.join()
    test2.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

In [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) you have to use [multiprocessing.Event()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event), not [threading.Event()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event)

---

**BTW:** And `multiprocessing.Event()` needs `is_set()` instead of `isSet()`

---

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Test1(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, event):
        super().__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.event.set()
        print('event set')

class Test2(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, event):
        super().__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.is_set():  # <--- `is_set()` instead of `isSet()`
            self.event.wait()
            print('event wait ended')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = multiprocessing.Event()  # <--- `multiprocessing` isntead of `threading`

    test1 = Test1(event)
    test2 = Test2(event)

    test1.start()
    test2.start()

    test1.join()
    test2.join()
```